# TypeError: Cannot read property 'serve:before' of undefined on Ionic CLI 2.2.1 + Gulp 4

Tags: ionic2, gulp, legacy

I am developing a Web Application that have a lot of legacy dependencies.

On the trial of updating some packages, I updated the gulp/gulpfile.js and tinkered then to run. Gulp was on version 3.5 and now is on 4.0.

By the way, the error thrown in the terminal by running : `ionic serve --address localhost --nobrowser` is :

```
 Error: spawn cordova EACCES
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:240:19)
    at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:415:16)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:63:19)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:834:11)
    at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:283:19)
    at bootstrapNodeJSCore (internal/bootstrap/node.js:622:3) 

Mind letting us know? https://github.com/driftyco/ionic-cli/issues

******************************************************
 Dependency warning - for the CLI to run correctly,      
 it is highly recommended to install/upgrade the following:     

 Please update your Cordova CLI to version  >=4.2.0 `npm install -g cordova`

******************************************************

TypeError: Cannot read property 'serve:before' of undefined
    at Object.runWithGulp (/usr/lib/node_modules/ionic/lib/cli.js:237:17)
    at Object.runr (/usr/lib/node_modules/ionic/lib/cli.js:194:18)
    at /usr/lib/node_modules/ionic/lib/cli.js:54:9
    at _fulfilled (/usr/lib/node_modules/ionic/node_modules/q/q.js:787:54)
    at /usr/lib/node_modules/ionic/node_modules/q/q.js:816:30
    at Promise.promise.promiseDispatch (/usr/lib/node_modules/ionic/node_modules/q/q.js:749:13)
    at /usr/lib/node_modules/ionic/node_modules/q/q.js:557:44
    at flush (/usr/lib/node_modules/ionic/node_modules/q/q.js:108:17)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:61:11)


Cannot read property 'serve:before' of undefined (CLI v2.2.1)

Your system information:

Cordova CLI: undefined
Ionic CLI Version: 2.2.1
Ionic App Lib Version: 2.2.0
ios-deploy version: Not installed
ios-sim version: Not installed
OS: Linux 5.4
Node Version: v10.16.3
Xcode version: Not installed
```

Then, some patch of the gulpfile.js :

```
gulp.task('build', gulp.series('bundle', 'copyTask', 'revTask', 'revReplaceTask'));
gulp.task('default', gulp.series('sassTask', 'cleanTask', 'build', 'watchTask'));
gulp.task('serve:before', gulp.series('cleanTask', 'watchTask', 'build'));
```

Before the tinkering, gulp.task('serve:before' [...]) functioned well. I guess it is related with the Ionic 2.2.1 CLI.

If someone could help me by a hint or an advice for mismatching the problem, I would be glad.

Comment: Hi, Did you find the solution?

Comment: No way... Still using the same versions. I choose another package, to implement WYSIWYG, to work with in.

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me while I upgraded Node to v12 which forced me to upgrade Gulp to v4.

The solution that worked for me is:

Go to npm\node_modules\ionic\lib\cli.js (Wherever it's located).

Change the following lines as such in cli.js:

```
237: if (true || gulp.tasks[beforeHook]) {
257: if (true || gulp.tasks[afterHook]) {
270: return Q.nfcall(null/*gulp.start.bind(gulp)*/, hookName)
```

Basically, the reason is that gulp.tasks and gulp.start don't exist in Gulp v4.

By putting true || in the first occurrences, gulp.tasks won't run and by putting null in the last occurrence, the gulp.start won't run.

I hope this helps the next people that encounter this problem.